# PHP Google OAuth2 Backend for Android

Tags: php, android, ruby-on-rails, oauth, google-plus

I followed this tutorial (http://blog.jachobsen.com/2013/08/10/google-oauth2-in-android-with-rails-backend/) to create the android part of the oauth2 authentication. At the end it provides the Rails part of the code for the server backend but I'm not very good with Rails and so am not too sure how to do it.

Does anyone know how I could create something similar but with PHP instead? I've had a look at this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ but I haven't been able to edit the code to get the access token, check if is valid and then return an API key.

Thank you very much, Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP sample you are looking at is not the latest for Google+ / authroization. You should start from the latest content in the Google+ documentation:

[Google+ PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php)

The quickstart shows you how to authorize the client and pass the credentials to your PHP backend for API calls.

If your server won't run Phar, you can get started with the sample code from the [PHP client library page](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) you linked and can update it to perform code exchange based on the code passed to your Android app or to authorize the user with an access token / authorization code from the web.

The following example performs code exchange for the web (as is done in the /connect endpoint in the quickstart sample):

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setDeveloperKey('YOUR_SIMPLE_API_KEY');

$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_GET['webcode'])) {
  $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
  $client->authenticate($_GET['webcode']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
  print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

To see the code work, you will need to generate a code from the web client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<span id="signinButton">
<span
      class="g-signin"
      data-callback="signinCallback"
      data-clientid="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
      data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
      data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
      data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
    </span>
  </span>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th><th>ID Token</th><th>Access token</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea id="code"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea id="idtok"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea id="atok"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
          var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
          po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();

      function signinCallback(resp) {
          console.log(resp);
          document.getElementById('code').value = resp.code;
          document.getElementById('idtok').value = resp.id_token;
          document.getElementById('atok').value = resp.access_token;
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then will pass it to the php script as the webcode parameter. I created a demo that runs from [wheresgus.com/phptest/stackdemo.php](http://wheresgus.com/phptest/stackdemo.php) and you can generate a code from http://wheresgus.com/phptest/gencode.html

An example GET would look like:

```
http://wheresgus.com/phptest/stackdemo.php?webcode=4/ajfCXQiZo-zRBAJGktP_eSYRha2s.YiEFJjWUiW4bEnp6UAPFm0GQNJMGhgI
```

In practice, you should be POSTing your code over HTTPS; but to get you started, hopefully this helps.

For your mobile clients, you should be able to verify using the ID token as follows:

- Securely pass the ID token to your application
- Verify the token is valid and belongs to the correct app
- Use the sub field to identify your user

The following code shows a function in the same app that verifies the token and uses simple API access to perform activities.list for the signed-in user:

```
if (isset($_GET['idtoken'])) {
  $attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($_GET['idtoken'], CLIENT_ID)
      ->getAttributes();
  $gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

  // At a minimum, make sure the token was for this app.
  if ($attributes["payload"]["aud"] == $client->getClientId()){
    $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities($gplus_id, 'public');
    print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';
  }else{
    print 'Authorization failed.';
  }
}
```

[Full code available here](http://wheresgus.com/phptest/phpdemo.zip).

Comment: Dam, my server does't support composer.

Comment: I'll see if there is an alternative example. If not, I could possibly put together another example.

Comment: Added a little code to make it easier for you. If you are receiving access tokens from Android, you should be able to authorize the PHP client using the token similarly to using the code and can then use the authorized client to authenticate the user.